Notion of commutativity for monads
I have read that in functional programming a monad is commutative if
a >>= \x -> b >>= \y -> f x y is equivalent to b >>= \y -> a >>= \x -> f x y,
i.e., order of side effects is not important.
A monad $(T, \eta, \mu)$ from the category theory perspective is commutative if it has a left-strength $\sigma$ and right-strength $\tau$ such that
$$\mu \circ T(\tau) \circ \sigma = \mu \circ T(\sigma) \circ \tau.$$
How are these two notions of commutativity related?
If I am not mistaken, then f >>= g can be written as $\mu(T(g)(f))$, but I do not see the connection.

They are equivalent. I will adopt Haskell notation, but the following makes sense in any higher-order functional programming language. There is an informal category $\mathbf{Hask}$ of types and functions, which you can think of as the category of sets for our purposes.
Recall that Haskell's notion of an endofunctor is defined by a function fmap :: (a → b) → (f a → f b). This is using the same function arrow thrice, which means that Haskell Functors (and Monads) are by definition enriched endofunctors (and enriched monads). Furthermore, $\mathbf{Hask}$ is a cartesian closed category, so enriched endofunctors and monads are the same thing as strong endofunctors and monads.
The tensorial strength is used to give semantics to Haskell expressions involving variables from the environment under binders (see Notions of computations and monads by Moggi). This is encapsulated by the following function:
strengthL :: Functor f => (a, f b) -> f (a, b)
strengthL (a, fb) = (\b -> (a, b)) <$> fb

Using this, we can write
strengthR :: Functor f => (f a, b) -> f (a, b)
strengthR = fmap swap . strengthL . swap

mulL :: Monad f => (f a, f b) -> f (a, b)
mulL = join . fmap strengthR . strengthL

mulR :: Monad f => (f a, f b) -> f (a, b)
mulR = join . fmap strengthL . strengthR

Now the definitions of mulL ($\mu \circ F(\tau) \circ \sigma$) and mulR ($\mu \circ F(\sigma) \circ \tau$) make sense for any strong monad, so we take their equality as the definition of a commutative monad. To connect this with your first definition, observe:
  mulL (fa, fb)
= join (strengthR <$> strengthL (fa, fb))
= join (strengthR <$> ((\b -> (fa, b)) <$> fb))
= join ((\b -> strengthR (fa, b)) <$> fb)
= fb >>= \b -> strengthR (fa, b)
= fb >>= \b -> (\a -> (a, b)) <$> fa
= fb >>= \b -> fa >>= \a -> return (a, b)

and similarly:
  mulR (fa, fb)
= fa >>= \a -> fb >>= \b -> return (a, b)

so we have landed on a special case of your first definition, for f a b = return (a, b). To see that this implies the general case, notice that your first definition says that mulL (fa, fb) >>= uncurry f = mulR (fa, fb) >>= uncurry f, but this clearly holds if mulL = mulR, so the two definitions are equivalent.

Thank you for your great answer.
I am particularly interested in the Giry Monad on Meas, for which I verified that the definition of the left-strength $\sigma(x,q) = \delta_x \otimes q$ is equivalent to the more general definition you have given.
Is your definition of left strength applicable for any  monad or do we have to put assumptions on the category?
For instance, that it is a cartesian closed category like Hask (however Meas is not cartesian closed).

The definition of left and right strengths makes sense in any monoidal category, and the equivalence of strength with enrichment holds in any symmetric monoidal closed category (you can drop the symmetry but then you have to be more careful). Are you sure the Giry monad is strong? This paper claims otherwise.

Ok, I see, thanks.
With my initial question I was trying to make sense of the commutativity of the Giry monad and its relation to the Fubini theorem. Thanks to your answer I understand this connection now.
I have taken the definition of the left-strength for the Giry monad from here. Whether the Giry monad is strong seems to depend on the considered monoidal structure of Meas.

I see, so it is strong with respect to the cartesian monoidal structure but not with respect to the "canonical" monoidal closed structure, which is a different one.
