Commutativity for monads modelling computation
$\newcommand{\llbracket}{[\hspace{-0.5mm}[}$
$\newcommand{\rrbracket}{]\hspace{-0.5mm}]}$
$\newcommand{\sem}[1]{\llbracket #1 \rrbracket}$
I came across the paper Notions of computation and monads by Eugenio Moggi.
In this approach the semantics of a programming languages is modelled by some strong monad $(T,\eta,\mu,\sigma)$.
Sequencing is defined as
$$\sem{\Gamma \vdash (\text{let } x = e_1 \text{ in } e_2)\colon T\tau_2} = \mu_{\sem{\tau_2}} \circ T(g_2) \circ \sigma_{\sem{\Gamma},\sem{\tau_1}}\circ \langle 1_{\sem{\Gamma}}, g_1 \rangle \colon \sem{\Gamma} \to T\sem{\tau_2},$$
where $\sem{\Gamma \vdash e_1\colon T\tau_1} = g_1\colon \sem{\Gamma} \to T\sem{\tau_1}$ and $\sem{\Gamma, x\colon \tau_1 \vdash e_2\colon T\tau_2} = g_2\colon \sem{\Gamma} \times \sem{\tau_1} \to T\sem{\tau_2}$.
In the programming sense commutativity is understood as
$$\sem{\Gamma \vdash (\text{let } x = e_1 \text{ in } (\text{let } y = e_2 \text{ in } e_3))\colon T\tau_3} = \sem{\Gamma \vdash (\text{let } y = e_2 \text{ in } (\text{let } x = e_1 \text{ in } e_3))\colon T\tau_3},$$
where $e_1$ does not depend on $y$ and $e_2$ does not depend on $x$.
On the other hand, commutativity in the categorical sense is understood as
$$\mu_{A\times B} \circ T(\tau_{A,B}) \circ \sigma_{TA, B}  = \mu_{A\times B} \circ T(\sigma_{A,B}) \circ \tau_{A,TB},$$
where $\sigma$ is the left-strength and $\tau$ is the right-strength.
My question is: How are these two notions of commutativity related?
I assume that the commutativity of the sequencing operations follows from the commutativity of the monad $T$.
My attempt to prove this:
Define
$$\sem{\Gamma \vdash (\text{let } x = e_1 \text{ in } (\text{let } y = e_2 \text{ in }  e_3) )\colon T\tau_3} \doteq g_{123} \colon \sem{\Gamma} \to T\sem{\tau_3}$$
$$\sem{\Gamma \vdash (\text{let } y = e_2 \text{ in } (\text{let } x = e_1 \text{ in }  e_3) )\colon T\tau_3} \doteq g_{213} \colon \sem{\Gamma} \to T\sem{\tau_3}$$
To show:
$g_{123} = g_{213}.$
Define some intermediate functions
$$\sem{\Gamma \vdash e_1\colon T\tau_1} \doteq g_1\colon \sem{\Gamma} \to T\sem{\tau_1}$$
$$\sem{\Gamma \vdash e_2\colon T\tau_2} \doteq g_2\colon \sem{\Gamma} \to T\sem{\tau_2}$$
$${\sem{\Gamma, x\colon \tau_1 \vdash (\text{let } y = e_2 \text{ in } e_3)\colon T\tau_3} \doteq g_{13}\colon \sem{\Gamma} \times \sem{\tau_1} \to T\sem{\tau_3}}$$
$${\sem{\Gamma, y\colon \tau_2 \vdash (\text{let } x = e_1 \text{ in } e_3)\colon T\tau_3} \doteq g_{23}\colon \sem{\Gamma} \times \sem{\tau_2} \to T\sem{\tau_3}}$$
$${\sem{\Gamma, x\colon \tau_1, y\colon \tau_2 \vdash e_3 \colon T\tau_3} \doteq g_{3}\colon \sem{\Gamma} \times \sem{\tau_1} \times \sem{\tau_2} \to T\sem{\tau_3}}$$
$${\sem{\Gamma, y\colon \tau_2, x\colon \tau_1 \vdash e_3 \colon T\tau_3} \doteq \tilde{g}_{3}\colon \sem{\Gamma} \times \sem{\tau_2} \times \sem{\tau_1} \to T\sem{\tau_3}}$$
$$\sem{\Gamma, y\colon \tau_2 \vdash e_1\colon T\tau_1} \doteq \tilde{g}_1\colon \sem{\Gamma}\times\sem{\tau_2} \to T\sem{\tau_1}$$
$$\sem{\Gamma, x\colon \tau_1 \vdash e_2\colon T\tau_2} \doteq \tilde{g}_2\colon \sem{\Gamma}\times\sem{\tau_1} \to T\sem{\tau_2}$$
We have $\tilde{g}_{3}(\gamma,y,x) = g_3(\gamma,x,y)$ and since $e_1$ does not depend on $y$ and $e_2$ does not depend on $x$ we have $\tilde{g}_1(\gamma,y) = g_1(\gamma)$ and $\tilde{g}_2(\gamma,x) = g_2(\gamma)$.
Substituting for the definition of sequencing gives

Now it seems obvious to me that we essentially build the tuples $\big(\gamma, g_1(\gamma), \tilde{g}_2(\gamma, g_1(\gamma))\big) = \big(\gamma, g_1(\gamma), g_2(\gamma)\big)$ before passing to $g_3$ and $\big(\gamma, g_2(\gamma), \tilde{g}_1(\gamma, g_1(\gamma))\big) = \big(\gamma, g_2(\gamma), g_1(\gamma)\big)$ before passing to $\tilde{g}_3$.
But I am not able to continue proof by only applying the manipulation rules for a commutative monad.
Any help is appreciated!

How is this different from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4929105/notion-of-commutativity-for-monads?

In that question, commutativity was expressed in terms of the bind operator. In contrast, in this post, commutativity is expressed in terms of the let programming construct with its semantics stated in the beginning of the post.
Can this be connected to the bind operator in an obvious way that I am failing to see?

That depends on your definition of "obvious", but it should be the same rough general idea. I will maybe write an answer later.

Here's a proof that $g_{123} = g_{213}$, as a commutative diagram using the commutativity of the monad in the middle (everything else is naturality), and omitting square brackets and obvious isomorphisms.


Thanks for the answer. Using the commutativity of the monad in the middle you mean the two paths $\Gamma \times T\tau_1 \times T\tau_2 \overset{\sigma \circ T\sigma}{\to} T^2(\Gamma \times \tau_1 \times \tau_2) \overset{\mu}{\to} T(\Gamma \times \tau_1 \times \tau_2)$?
And the obvious isomorphisms would be reorderings $\beta_{A,B}\colon A \times B \to B \times A$?

Yes, that's what I mean.

Okay, I feel like there is still some work left to be done to show that this diagram actually commutes.
For instance $\Gamma \times T\tau_1 \times T\tau_2 \overset{\sigma}{\to} T(\Gamma \times \tau_1 \times T\tau_2)$ requires some details to deal with $\Gamma$ as the signature of the left strength would be $\sigma\colon T(\tau_1 \times \tau_2) \to T(\tau_1 \times T\tau_2)$.
But maybe I can take it from here.

Sure, that's why I said the obvious isomorphisms were omitted. The diagram is enough to convey the idea of the proof; checking all the equations in detail is routine work.
